# How can I create the XML::Simple data structure using a Perl XML SAX parser?

Tags: xml, perl, dom, parsing, sax

**Summary**: I am looking a fast XML parser (most likely a wrapper around some standard SAX parser) which will produce per-record data structure 100% identical to those produced by [XML::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple).

**Details**:

We have a large code infrastructure which depends on processing records one-by-one and expects the record to be a data structure in a format produced by XML::Simple since it always used XML::Simple since early Jurassic era.

An example simple XML is:

```
<root>
    <rec><f1>v1</f1><f2>v2</f2></rec>
    <rec><f1>v1b</f1><f2>v2b</f2></rec>
    <rec><f1>v1c</f1><f2>v2c</f2></rec>
</root>
```

And example rough code is:

```
sub process_record { my ($obj, $record_hash) = @_; # do_stuff }
my $records = XML::Simple->XMLin(@args)->{root};
foreach my $record (@$records) { $obj->process_record($record) };
```

As everyone knows XML::Simple is, well, simple. And more importantly, it is very slow and a memory hog—due to being a DOM parser and needing to build/store 100% of data in memory. So, it's not the best tool for parsing an XML file consisting of large amount of small records record-by-record.

However, re-writing the entire code (which consist of large amount of "process_record"-like methods) to work with standard SAX parser seems like an big task not worth the resources, even at the cost of living with XML::Simple.

I'm looking for an existing module which will probably be based on a SAX parser (or anything fast with small memory footprint) which can be used to produce `$record` hashrefs one by one based on the XML pictured above that can be passed to `$obj->process_record($record)` and be 100% identical to what XML::Simple's hashrefs would have been.

I don't care much what the interface of the new module is; e.g whether I need to call `next_record()` or give it a callback coderef accepting a record.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) has a *simplify* method which you can call on a XML element which according to docs says:

> Return a data structure suspiciously similar to XML::Simple's

Here is an example:

```
use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        rec => \&rec,
    }
)->parsefile( 'data.xml' );


sub rec {
    my ($twig, $rec) = @_;
    my $data = $rec->simplify;
    say Dumper $data;
    $rec->purge;
}
```

NB. The *$rec->purge* cleans out the record immediately from memory.

Running this against your XML example produces this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'f1' => 'v1',
          'f2' => 'v2'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'f1' => 'v1b',
          'f2' => 'v2b'
        };

$VAR1 = {
          'f1' => 'v1c',
          'f2' => 'v2c'
        };
```

Which I hope is *suspiciously* like what comes out of XML::Simple :)

/I3az/

Answer (score 6):

As the author of XML::Simple, I'd just like to correct some misconceptions in your question.

XML::Simple isn't a DOM parser, in fact it isn't a parser at all.  It delegates all parsing duties to either a SAX parser or XML::Parser.  The speed of parsing will depend on which parser module is the default on your system.  When you run 'make test' for the XML::Simple distribution, the output will list the default parser.

If the default parser on your system is XML::SAX::PurePerl then it will be slow and more importantly buggy too.  If that's the case then I'd recommend installing either XML::Expat or XML::ExpatXS for an immediate speed up.  (Whichever SAX parser is installed last will be the default from that point).

Having said that, your requirements are a bit contradictory, you want something that returns your whole document as a hash and yet you don't want a parser that slurps the whole document into memory.

I understand your short-term goals, but as a longer term solution, I'd recommend migrating your code to XML::LibXML.  It is a DOM parser but it's very fast because all the grunt work is done in C.  Best of all the built-in XPath support makes it even simpler to use than XML::Simple - see [this article](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=490846).

Comment: (1) we have experimented with changing back-end parsers via `$ENV{XML_SIMPLE_PREFERRED_PARSER}`. It provided significant speedup, but NOT comparable to pure C solution (XPath module). So our conclusion was that a large amount of time is spent on building the entire data tree in memory as opposed to just parsing.

Comment: (2) We don't want to return the whole document - we want an iterator that returns 1-level-deep tags as individual hashes, without storing the whole thing in memory (at least in Perl - not sure what the underlying XS module does)

Comment: (3) Unfortunately, the "correct" solution is not feasible - I CAN attempt to change the implementation of one module (whose API is basically "give me the next hashref"); but changing every single user of that module to use XPath is looking like too much of an effort to justify. Thus my looking for something that can emulate XML::Simple's putput per individual 2d level tag.

Comment: (4) ... and thanks for feedback! One of the beauties of SO :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [XML::LibXML::Reader](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML::Reader).

Comment: Downvote: ⑴ Link text does not match link target. ⑵ Neither Reader nor SAX fulfil the question's requirement. ⑶ [Grant already recommended LibXML one month ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912462#2916863)

Comment: @daxim: XML::LibXML::Reader provides a 'pull' API to the libxml parsing library.  This is an entirely different paradigm to the more commonly used DOM/XPath API of XML::LibXML and also seems like a good fit for your stated requirement of an 'iterator'.  Don't dismiss it out of hand.